# Drupal 7 e-mail driven forum (mailcomment)

Tags: emails, nodes

I've been tasked to set up a forum on drupal 7 that can support outgoing e-mail notifications with incoming e-mail posting for a forum section akin to Google Groups. I.e. a fully e-mail integrated forum where content comments and threads can be generated and responded to entirely by e-mail.

My question is, how do I achieve this? In most cases, I'm finding deadends with dependencies as it does not seem mature on drupal 7; many of the modules only have recommended or released versions for drupal 6. In the first case I tried, my host (hostgator) did not support the required PHP module dependencies.

I have tried:

http://drupal.org/project/femail
Issue: Unable to install PECL MailParse a requirement of femail.  Our host (hostgator) won't support: 'not compatible' apparently.

Listhandler
Issue: Untried. No D7 version.

and the most promising route:

Mailhandler/Mailcomment with Notifications and Messaging
Guides: 
hyperlinkhttp: drupal.org/node/1045918
hyperlinkhttp: peterthorndycraft.com/tutorial/mailhandler

Issue: Depenendies that cannot be met.

From the mailcomment INSTALL.txt:

Dependencies:
- Mailhandler (matching version required - i.e., if you are using Mail Comment
  7.x-2.0-alpha5, you must use Mailhandler 7.x-2.0-alpha5)
- Notifications and Messaging (7.x-4.x branch)

The 7.x-4.x branch appears to not exist: http://drupal.org/project/messaging

I have tried it with the 7.x-1.0 version but without success.

EDIT: My issue is identical (the OP is not me) to: 
http:// drupal.org/node/1889550

EDIT: I have managed to be able to create nodes via e-mail using the mailhandler/notif+messaging framework, but as of yet, unable to get replies from e-mails to trigger new comments.

My question is really: is achieving this aim possible with D7? What framework have people achieved this in in other D7 sites? I'm reasonably new to Drupal, so sorry if there is something obvious I haven't tried.

Thanks

PS: Couldn't post all the hypoerlinks i was referencing. J

Comment: have you gone through this link? http://drupal.org/node/793564

Comment: Thanks Mohammed. I haven't read through this but it looks like it's for D6, not D7. However, the author of this post is the same as one of the guides I posted, so it looks like I should look for their other posts.

Answer (score 1):

This is in no way trivial since you will need to setup an email SERVER to react to certain emails and trigger a drupal 7 process. I have been tinkering with a bunch of modules and the most promising is [og_mailinglist](http://drupal.org/project/og_mailinglist) Within the module you will find a lot of information and Documentation of how to achieve this. You might even want to read through [this](http://drupal.org/node/1035930) to meet the makers

Even so the requirements are really tough and it is a project of several weeks if not months. most customers think this should be easy, well it is not. And it has security implications that have to be thoroughly solved. You are allowing an email to add content!

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks reptilex. I've just made an edit in my post in that I have been able to create nodes by e-mail, but not trigger comments by e-mail replies. I have been meaning to try organic groups also, so I'll look into this too.